# How to get returning data from the latest input that match each key cell

Tags: google-sheets

How to make status column get the latest status for each motor code from log record. I also attached the sample sheet here please help, thank you.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FObfeQ652jfLy5M_pFQcEgnLoOYmdvJ_mC1gn2QldBY/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `QUERY()` with `ROW()` - paste one and fill down

```
=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(ROW('Mortor Status'!B$2:B)),'Mortor Status'!B$2:C},"select Col3 where Col2 ='"&A2&"' order by Col1 desc limit 1",0)
```

`ARRAYFORMULA(ROW())` to get number of each row to sort desc

`select Col3` to get only one column which is "Status"

`where Col2 ='"&A2&"'` to filter only "Code" like S0-01 ,...

`order by...desc` to re-sort to get the last one to the top

`limit 1` to get only one row to be able to fill next row

I hope it'll help you